# How to parse a date of format "2016-08-07T08:50:06.000Z" using Jackson and ObjectMapper

Tags: java-8, jackson

I am trying to parse a Json in the above format using Jackson and Java 8, but unable to do so.
Here is my code -

```
String date = "{\"requestDate\":\"2016-08-07T08:50:06.000Z\"}";
TestPOJO testPOJO = new ObjectMapper().readValue(date, TestPOJO.class);
System.out.println("testPOJO" + testPOJO.toString());
```

TestPojo.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class TestPOJO {
    @JsonProperty("requestDate")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS", timezone = "GMT")
    private LocalDateTime testDate;
}
```

However for the same pattern I am able to parse it to `Calendar` Object.
Is there a way pattern to directly parse it as `LocalDateTime` object ?

Answer (score 1):

Registering the [jackson-datatype-jdk8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8) module will solve your issue.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```